# how can 'puts' stop a hanging command?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying out the 'spreadsheet' gem and noticed something I haven't encountered before:

```
book = Spreadsheet.open "public/tickers.xls"
# => #<Spreadsheet::Excel::Workbook:0x5c16420>

puts book.worksheet(0)
# => #Spreadsheet::Excel::Worksheet:0x000000019494a8

book.worksheet(0)
# => This command hangs for a long time.
```

The difference between the second and third command is just the `puts` statement. How would this change the effect of the command to return immediately rather than hanging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever the result of calling `book.worksheet(0)` is, it has a very efficient `to_s` and a very inefficient `inspect` method. That's one possibility.

`Worksheet#inspect` loops through all instance variables and concatenates their string representations, so if it either has a huge number of instance variables, or if one of the instance variables points to an object which has a huge string representation (or a very slow `to_s`) method, it will take a long time.

OTOH, `Worksheet` doesn't have a `to_s` method, so it inherits the one from `Object` which is extremely fast since it only prints the memory address and class.